# Position/orientation of model in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have set a specific orientation for my model in Revit, but as it gets loaded in the Forge Viewer is appears that the viewer overrides the coordinates of what I've set in Revit.

Where/how can I edit the "home-screen" for my model in the viewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this **in my experience**, one is using `Set current view as Home` in the Revit ViewCube, another is using `Viewer3D` state API in the Forge Viewer.

In the Revit part, you can do this in this ways:

1. Open a 3D view, then duplicate it with an new name. **Don't use the default name {3D}**.
2. Set a specific camera orientation in this 3D view, then click the `Set current view as Home` in the Revit ViewCube to save current view as the default view.
3. Pick this 3D view in the `Publish Settings` to tell the Forge Model Derivative service to translate this for viewing in the Forge Viewer, then click `save` button to assign this 3D view as the Web view for the Forge.
4. Save this Revit project and upload it to the Forge for model translation. Forge Model Derivative service will use the camera position in the Home view you set in the above steps as the default camera position of the Forge Viewer.

In Forge Viewer side, you can do this:

1. Set a specific camera orientation in your viewer app, then call `viewer.getStatus( { viewport: true } )` to get current camera state (One time only).
2. Remember this camera state somewhere.
3. Restore this camera state after all geometry is loaded via the `viewer.restoreState( thisCameraState )` every time.
4. If you want to override the default Home view of the Forge Viewer, you can simply call `viewer.utilities.autocam.setCurrentViewAsHome()` after the step 3.

==== Update ====

If you still have some problem related to this issue, you can consider providing a reproducible case demonstrating that, I will gladly analysis for you. Those following items should be in the reproducible case:

1. A short exact description of what you are trying to achieve. The behavior you observe versus what you expect, and why this is a problem.
2. A complete yet minimal sample source model to run a test in.
3. A complete yet minimal Forge app that can be run and debugged with a simple procedure to analyze its behavior lives in the sample model.
4. Detailed step-by-step instructions for reproducing the issue, e.g. which element to pick, what command to launch etc.

If your reproducible case could not be posted here publicly, please send it to the `forge.help@autodesk.com` and **remove sensitive data or information before you send**.

Hope this help.

Comment: I followed your exact steps for the Revit part and I successfully generated a new default "Home" for the model inside Revit. I also saved this view in the Publish Settings. Everything looked good on the Revit end, but as I load the new URN into my app, the model gets the same old centered and zoomed-out location as before. Strange. I really thought this would work as it looked good in Revit. Seems like the Forge Viewer is overriding the Revit setting even after these settings.

Comment: It's not recommended to upload the model file with the same name to the Forge Data Management Service. If you do so, you have to add a parameter `x-ads-force: true` to the request header while calling the API `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job`. This will force the Model Derivative Service replaces previously translated output file types with the newly generated derivatives. Here is the documentation: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/

Comment: It's recommended to rename your modified model with an new name before uploading model to the Forge server. This will avoid derivative result replacement issue of model files with same name in the Model Derivative service.

Comment: Your translation results might remain the old one if you didn't add `x-ads-force: true` to header for requesting a translation job or upload modified file with the new name. Please retry it again, the Revit part workflow is working fine in my side.

Comment: Thanks. I'll modify how I proceed and test that out.

Comment: I was able to change the orientation that way - but - the zoom and the centered align stay the same. Meaning, I am able to retrieve wheter I see the model from top-down or perspective etc, but I am not able to retrieve the zoom and the align (I want to have my model placed with a zoom-in in the left section of the screen)

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible case for me to do some test on your model? The detail of the reproducible case is added to my answer above.